# 1/2" OD Compression to 1/2" barb fitting?

Tags: plumbing, water, valve, plumbing-fixture

I have a 1/2" copper pipe which has a 1/2" nom compression x 1/2" OD compression stop on it. I'd like to be able to put a 1/2" barb fitting to connect this to a hose.

I can't find anything which would screw onto the male threads on the valve body to get me the barb?

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

There are no options short of removing the compression stop valve and replacing it, or putting in a short piece of 1/2" OD tubing connected to a new valve with a barbed outlet. threads for compression fittings are not designed to hold any pressure themselves or to mate up to anything other than the compression nut designed for them.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicion. I think I will try and find a sharkbite to male thread adapter and go from there. I don't want to sweat something on there.

Answer (score 0):

there are fitting that go from a 1/2 compression fitting to a barb fitting with for a 1/2 id rubber hose  - PN 13033 made by Derale